# how to apply filter condition in percentage string column using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image: original data]I am working on below df but unable to apply filter in percentage field,but it is working normal excel.
 I need to apply filter condition > 100.00% in the particular field using pandas.

I tried reading it from Html,csv and excel in pandas but unable to use condition.
it requires float conversion but not working with given data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Its not duplicate ,i have check all pandas question ,then only i created this question 
 for  conversion error and filter problem in pandas with percentage column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that the values you have are read as strings in Pandas:

```
data = ['4,700.00%', '3,900.00%', '1,500.00%', '1,400.00%', '1,200.00%', '0.15%', '0.13%', '0.12%', '0.10%', '0.08%', '0.07%']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['data']
```

printing the df:

```
       data
0   4,700.00%
1   3,900.00%
2   1,500.00%
3   1,400.00%
4   1,200.00%
5      0.15%
6      0.13%
7      0.12%
8      0.10%
9      0.08%
10     0.07%
```

then:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.rstrip('%').str.replace(',','').astype('float')
df_filtered = df[df['data'] > 100]
```

Results:

```
     data
0  4700.0
1  3900.0
2  1500.0
3  1400.0
4  1200.0
```

Comment: thanks @Tabbakhh,my data has more than 1500,its showing error -'pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers'

Comment: @pythonlearner - No worries. Please check the new edited answer and let me know if everything goes well

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,200.00',kindly use my exact given data.Both 1200.00% and 0.07%  creating problem in conversion I think.

Comment: data reading from the csv ,html or excel, pandas giving data as 1,200.00,that comma in the value creating a problem,how to solve it ?without comma your code working fine @Tabbakhh

Comment: @pythonlearner - Please mark my answer as a solution if it worked for you. Also, please insert a sample data rather than a screenshot if you do post any other questions, it make it easier for us to copy the exact numbers (:

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code as well`.str.rstrip('%')` and `.str.replace(',','').astype('float')` it working fine